# Why can't I total up these values?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am building a gradebook web app. I wanted the app to have the ability to calculate grades upon pushing the Final button. However, it's not working for some reason:

```js
   var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var r = 0;//how many rows; row index
      var c = 1;//how many columns

      //make a table
        //table must be able to add rows
        //table cells should be editable
          //save changes?
          //

      //make a table head row
      //all table columns must have a table head
      //**
      // var firstRow= myTable.insertRow(0);

      function addRow(){
        //make a new row
        var row = myTable.insertRow(r);
        //use a while loop to keep creating row cells until you reach last column
        var i = 0;
        while(i<c){
          var cell = row.insertCell(i);
          cell.innerHTML ="Students[i]";
          i++;
        }
        r++;
      }
      function addColumn(){
        //make new column
        //increment column
        var tHead = document.createElement("th");


        var allRows= document.getElementsByTagName("tr");//get all rows
        //put tHead in first row
        allRows[0].append(tHead);
        var dateTable = document.createElement("input");
        dateTable.type = "date";
        tHead.appendChild(dateTable);
        //tHead.innerHTML = (c*2);
        //add a new cell for each row
        var j =1;
        while(j<allRows.length){
          var row2 = allRows[j];
          var cell2 = row2.insertCell(c);
          cell2.innerHTML = j;
          j++;
        }
        c++;
        f++;
        //if there already id a final row, delete it
      }

      function unEdit(){
        //go through every cell
        //save input value to a variable
        //remove the input cell
        var valArray =[];

        document.querySelectorAll("td>input").forEach(input => {
          var num = parseInt(input.value);
          valArray.push(num);
          input.remove();
        });

        //put input value into innerhtml of td
        var i = 0;
        document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(td =>{
          td.innerHTML=valArray[i];
          i++;
        });

        }
      function editTable(){

        var allCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for(var k=0; k<allCells.length; k++){
          var oldText= allCells[k];
          var input = document.createElement("input");

          input.type ="number";
          input.max = 100;
          input.min = 0;

          //before making all cells input, save previous innerhtml to var,
          //make it into a num instead of a string, and put that value into input

          var prev = allCells[k].innerHTML;
          prev = parseInt(prev);
          input.value = prev;

          allCells[k].innerHTML = "";
          allCells[k].appendChild(input);
          input.onblur;
      }
    }
    function deleteRow(){
      document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(1);
      r--;
    }
    function deleteColumn(){
      //go through each row
      //delete cell at each index
      var everyRow = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for(var p=0; p<everyRow.length; p++){
        everyRow[p].deleteCell(-1);
      }
      c--;
      var finalButton = document.getElementById("final");
      finalButton.enabled = true;
    }

    //final grade column
    function finalRow(){
      //make a <thead>
      //make a new cell going down
      var finalHead = document.createElement("th");
      finalHead.innerHTML= "Final Grade";
      var theseRows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      theseRows[0].append(finalHead);

      for(var t =1; t<theseRows.length; t++){
        //go through every cell in the row
        //total up the numbers and put it in the final cell
        var finalTotal=0;
        for(var e =1; e< theseRows[t].length; e++){
          var numero = theseRows[t][e].value;
          numero = parseInt(numero);
          console.log(numero);
          finalTotal += numero;
        }
        //add up the innerhtmls and put it in finalCell
        var finalCell = theseRows[t].insertCell(-1);
        finalCell.innerHTML = finalTotal;
      }
      c++;
      //disable final button
      var finalButton = document.getElementById("final");
      finalButton.disabled = true;
      var days = document.getElementById("days");
      days.disabled = true;

    }
    addRow();
    addColumn();


    //make a table head row at the top

    //maybe add a print button?
    //add a final grade column

    //make it so that final row stays final when add new students and days

    //do final funtion inside of unEdit() at the end?????
```

```css
table,td,th{
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
```

```html
    <table id = "myTable"></table>
 
   

    </script>
    <button onclick ="addRow()">Students</button>
    <button onclick ="addColumn()" id ="days">Days</button>
    <button onclick="editTable()">Edit</button>
    <button onclick="unEdit()">Unedit</button>
    <button onclick="deleteRow()">Delete Row</button>
    <button onclick="deleteColumn()">Delete Column</button>
    <button onclick ="finalRow()" id ="final">Final</button>
    <button>Print</button>
```

In the finalRow() function, I can't figure out why the total I keep getting is always 0. Why doesn't it add up the value of the cells? I wanted it to go through every row, get the number values from each cell and total it up. It seems like the issue is with the "numero" variable, but I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first error is because you **forgot to declare the variable `f`**, you declared only the variables `r` and `c` above.

the second is in the function `DeleteRow()` there is an indexing error because it finds a negative value when deleting the last row. If you don't even want him to delete the last row, I suggest using a `Try-Catch` to deal with this error.

Comment: Thanks.Do you see how I can make the finalRow() function perform the intended task?  I keep getting 0 in each column, when I intended it to have the total of all cells in the row.

Comment: @J.slack you can try using:

`document.getElementById('myTable').rows[0].cells.length`. To collect the size of the first column. To collect the size of all columns, you will just need a FOR loop

Comment: Ok. So I have to use .cells. Thanks a lot!